# Can i make a line of code run from the first load of the webpage until closing?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, if i put

```
console.log("hello world")
```

It'll log "hello world" to console just 1 time, at the load of the page. Can i make this code run not just 1 time, but until the web page closed?

Comment: Give some clarifying to your question. What do you mean 'until the web page closed'? If you meant 'repeat every second' then you could put you log inside `SetInterval` function and your final code would looks like this `SetInterval(()=> console.log('Hello World!'),1000);`

Comment: @Jaood_xD Yeah sorry. SetInterval is "almost" solving my problem with 1000ms as i need like 1 second of execuations. It solves but "timing a code" is not the thing i'm looking. I think my question should be like this; "what can we do in situations like we cannot listen any events on the page, but still need to execute a bunch of code in a specific moment". Is the setInterval the only solution for something like this? Another example; when we're unable to listen events but need to run a code automatically, immedietaly after an if else condition turnes true on the webpage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
while (1) console.log("Hello, World!");
```

Comment: This is not recommended at all, it will cause the webpage (and sometimes browser) to freeze due to high cpu/memory usage.

Comment: @CallumOKane yes, it's not the best practice for a situation like this but it corresponds 100% true to my question as an answer so I think my question wasn't descriptive enough

Comment: @InfernoCheese so i will accept your comment as an answer to this topic and start a more descriptive topic to my problem